# Alfresco: Unable to search via Lucene by date

Tags: lucene, alfresco

I am writing an Alfresco webscript to search for content by date, and not having any luck.

My query looks like this:

```
PATH:\"/app:company_home/st:sites/cm:mysite/cm:documentLibrary/cm:News/*\" 
AND @cm\\:created:[2013-09-25T00:00:00.000Z TO NOW]
```

I have three folders in my **News** folder:

- Folder 1, created on 2013-09-24
- Folder 2, created on 2013-09-24
- Folder 3, created on 2013-09-**25**   <- Created a day after the other two.

My Lucene search is always returning 3 items. **Why does it return three items when the first two were created before the 25th?**

And why do I have to search with a range to get any results? Why does this not work when [Alfresco's documentation](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Search#Finding_nodes_by_date_and_time_property_values) says that truncated datetime formats are supported?

```
PATH:\"/app:company_home/st:sites/cm:mysite/cm:documentLibrary/cm:News/*\" 
AND @cm\\:created:"2013-09-25"
```

Alfresco version: 3.3

**EDIT:**

I have checked that the following lines exist in `alfresco/model/dataTypeAnalyzers.properties`:

```
d_dictionary.datatype.d_date.analyzer=org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.lucene.analysis.DateAnalyser
# d_dictionary.datatype.d_datetime.analyzer=org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.lucene.analysis.DateAnalyser
d_dictionary.datatype.d_datetime.analyzer=org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.lucene.analysis.DateTimeAnalyser
```

Comment: Alfresco 3.3 is ancient! What happens if you try upgrading to the latest version, does that fix it?

Comment: I would love to upgrade Alfresco but it is not something I am able to do. Another team manages it, and they are planning an upgrade next year. I share your frustration.

Comment: did you try without the Zulu?, e.g. [2013-09-25T00:00:00.000+02:00 TO NOW]

Comment: this should work in 3.3 @cm\\:created:"2013-09-25" so I'm not sure why you're using a range query. I've even used date queries in version 2.2.

Answer (score 1):

A working example from version 3.x in a freemarker template

```
<#assign startPunt = companyhome.childrenByLuceneSearch["TYPE:\"wn:zaak\" AND @wn\\:vernietigingsdatum:[MIN TO "+date?string("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")+"] "]>
```